# Flutter RestfullApi Operations

Tags: flutter, dart, http, dio

I'm working with a Flutter RESTful API using both the Dio and http packages, but only my `fetchData()` function is functioning correctly. The other functions are not working, and I'm having trouble performing a POST request. I've searched online and tried various solutions, but none of them have worked so far. Could you please help me troubleshoot the issue? Here's the code I'm currently working with:

```dart
class LoginService {
  final Dio dio = Dio();
  final String baseUrl = 'http://muratkilinc.com/mintsis/web_json.php';
  final url = Uri.parse('http://muratkilinc.com/mintsis/web_json.php');

  Future fetchData() async {
    try {
      final response = await dio.get(baseUrl);
      print(response.statusCode);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final List<dynamic> responseData = response.data;
        List<DataModel> users = responseData
            .map((userJson) => DataModel.fromMap(userJson))
            .toList();
        print(users);
        // kullanıcı adı]);
        print(response.statusCode); //status kodu
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  Future<void> addData() async {
    var newUser = {
      "userID": 7,
      "username": "yeni_kullanici",
      "name": "Yeni",
      "surname": "Kullanıcı",
      "password": "e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e",
      "typeName": "Öğrenci",
      "departmentName": "Sosyal Hizmet Bölümü"
    };

    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        url,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: jsonEncode(newUser),
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print("Veri başarıyla eklendi");
      } else {
        print(
            "Veri ekleme işlemi başarısız oldu. StatusCode: ${response.statusCode}");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm check your functions and 'addData' is working but your backend not working actually, I think.
https://gist.github.com/mrasityilmaz/198067120be36f2335a45523b34eb757

Answer (score 1):

When posting a question try to add the error message so we can pinpoint where it fails exactly.
Also, you should choose **between** Dio and Http, both are libraries to help you perform requests, just choose one each have their pro and cons depending on the project size and such.

Regarding your question, if you stick with Dio, here is how to perform a POST request:

```
var newUser = {
      "userID": 7,
      "username": "yeni_kullanici",
      "name": "Yeni",
      "surname": "Kullanıcı",
      "password": "e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e",
      "typeName": "Öğrenci",
      "departmentName": "Sosyal Hizmet Bölümü"
    };

Response response = await dio.post(
  'https://api.example.com/endpoint',
  data: newUser,
);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  // Request was successful
  print(response.data);
} else {
  // Request failed
  print('Request failed with status code ${response.statusCode}');
}
```

Please provide more context if this answer is not enough to make it work :)